# What if I change field in a Topological Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-topology, quantum-field-theory

Of course I'm talking about the algebraic notion of *field*.

In a few words, if a TQFT consists of a functor $Z\colon Cob(n)\to \mathbf{Vec}_k$, I'm wondering if there are sensible relations among different choices of $k$... Some example coming to my mind:

1. Fix a real valued TQFT. Can I turn the functor sending objects to $Z(M)\otimes_\mathbb R\mathbb C$ (the "complexification" of the real vector space associated to $M$) into a complex valued TQFT?
2. What if I consider, in general, a $k$-valued TQFT and a $K$-valued TQFT (with $K$ an extension of $k$)? What if $K$ is finite, infinite, algebraic, Galois or not, positive charateristic or not, etc etc.?

(Feel free to retag the question).

Answer (score 7):

Yes it makes sense to talk about TQFTs over different fields and yes you can ask the usual kind of questions about base extensions and descent.  You may find [this recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0657) of Etingof-Gelaki interesting (it's about the same question for fusion categories, but via Turaev-Viro those give TQFTs).

The answer to your first question is trivial: you have a functor Cob(n)-> Vec_k and you compose it with the base extension functor Vec_k -> Vec_K.  I'm not sure what the question is in your second question.

Comment: The answer to your first question is trivial: you have a functor Cob(n)-> Vec_k and you compose it with the base extension functor Vec_k -> Vec_K.

I don't think it is so trivial: a TQFT must have some special properties the simple composition $F=(-\otimes_k K)\circ Z_k\colon Cob(n)\to Vec_k\to Vec_K$ does *not* have; for example what's happen if i want to compute $F$ on the disjoint union of two manifolds?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: I assume the special properties you mention are that the tqft must be a *symmetric monoidal functor*. The base change functor is symmetric monoidal so these properties (really structures) are preserved. 